# Increase size of a section if needed

Tags: html, css

I am making a website with sections that have a viewport of 95%, but not everyone has a big screen and may need more to see the content in a specific section.
  My sections all have a div with the text in it, but I would like to know if there's any way to increase the section size if the div inside it becomes the big, but is atleast a viewport of 95%.
  Here's the section CSS:

```
section {
height: 95vh;
}
```

Here's the div css:

```
#startInhoud
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

background-color:white;
border-radius: 20px;
border: solid;
border-top-color: black;
border-width: 2px;

top: 3px;
width: 75%;
display: inline: block;
}
```

And here's how it looks with text:

```
 <section id="start">
<font face="print_boldregular" size="10">Start</font>
<div id="startInhoud">
Hallo, ik ben Sam en ik maak websites en andere digitale dingen.<br>
Ik heet u welkom op mijn site, waarvoor bent u hier:<br>
<a href="#websitesSnap" class="eigen scroll" class="scroll">Een eigen website</a><br>
<font size="4"><i>Wilt u een eigen website voor een lage prijs? Kijk naar wat ik aanbied.</i></font><br>
<a href="#klantSnap" class="eigen scroll">Inloggen</a><br>
<font size="4"><i>Log hier in op uw account om te kijken hoever uw site is, als u een bestaande klant bent.</i></font><br><br>
U kunt in de navigatiebalk meer mogelijkheden vinden.<br>
</div>
</section>
```

id="start" only has a line to change the background color in its css.

If anyone has an idea it is appreciated.
  Thanks in advance!

Comment: link to a http://jsfiddle.net would be nice.

Comment: Remove the height attribute for the section. It will work.

Comment: I want it to be 95vh minimum and expand if needed, is there any way to do that?